# QueryDSL Issue with any() and InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: jpa, querydsl

I am currently having an issue with setting up a predicate where the collection is utilizing InheritanceType.JOINED.  I am currenlty using QueryDSL 3.6.3.

I am attempting to create a predicate against the base class as follows:

```
final QCollector collector = QCollector.collector;
final JPAQuery query = new JPAQuery(entityManager);
query.from(collector).where(collector.parents.any().desc.eq("test"));
final List<Collector> results = query.list(collector);
```

This JPQL is generated:

```
select collector 
from Collector collector 
where exists (select 1 from collector.parents as collector_parents_1f637
              where collector_parents_1f637.desc = ?1)
```

And results in the following SQL

```
select collector0_.ID as ID1_1_ from COLLECTOR collector0_ where exists (select 1 from PARENT parents1_ where collector0_.ID=parents1_.PARENT_ID and parents1_1_.DESC=?)
```

This SQL is incorrect as it does not join to BASE for DESC. Is there something I am missing in my JPA mapping for am I building my predicate incorrectly?

Sample Code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "BASE")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class Base implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "BASE_ID")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "CODE")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "DESC")
    private String desc;
    ...

@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "BASE_ID", referencedColumnName = "BASE_ID")  
public class Parent extends Base {

    @Column(name = "PARENT_ID")    private Long parentId;
    ...

@Entity@Table(name = "COLLECTOR")
public class Collector implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "ID")
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parentId")
    private List<Parent> parents;
    ....

CREATE TABLE BASE (
    BASE_ID NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(10),
    DESC VARCHAR(200),
    PRIMARY KEY (BASE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE PARENT (
    BASE_ID NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (BASE_ID)
);

CREATE TABLE COLLECTOR (
    ID NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
    PARENT_ID NUMERIC(18,0) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Comment: Does a simple query like "select p from Parent p where p.desc = ?" work?

Comment: Yes @TimoWestkämper  it does work, the join is properly made.
'select parent0_.BASE_ID as BASE_ID1_0_, parent0_1_.CODE as CODE2_0_, parent0_1_.DESC as DESC3_0_, parent0_.PARENT_ID as PARENT_ID1_2_ from PARENT parent0_ inner join BASE parent0_1_ on parent0_.BASE_ID=parent0_1_.BASE_ID where parent0_1_.DESC=?'

I believe this is actually the same issue here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29796642/hibernate-is-using-wrong-table-name-for-order-by-expression-with-three-level-inh?s=17|0.4220

I plan on submitting a defect with Hibernate as time allows.